# Hibernate: addQueryHint issue when using setMaxResults

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm using hibernate `5.4.23` and oracle `12c`:

Consider this query:

```
.createQuery("select m from OrgMessage m " +
               "where m.userId=:userId and m.peerId=:peerId" +
               "order by m.message_id desc")
         .addQueryHint("index(org_message ix_org_message_userid_peerid)")
         .setParameter("userId", userId)
         .setParameter("peerId", peerId)
```

Hibernate generates this sql (which is correct):

```
SELECT
    /*+ index(orgmessage0_ ix_org_message_userid_peerid) */
    orgmessage0_.message_id,
    orgmessage0_.user_id,
    orgmessage0_.peer_id,
    orgmessage0_.msg_content,
FROM
    org_message orgmessage0_
WHERE
    orgmessage0_.user_id =?
    AND orgmessage0_.peer_id =?
ORDER BY
    orgmessage0_.message_id DESC
```

But, by adding `setMaxResults(10)`, hibernate puts the hint in the outer select (which is wrong):

```
SELECT /*+ index(orgmessage0_ ix_org_message_userid_peerid) */ * FROM (
    SELECT
        orgmessage0_.message_id,
        orgmessage0_.user_id,
        orgmessage0_.peer_id,
        orgmessage0_.msg_content,
    FROM
        org_message orgmessage0_
    WHERE
        orgmessage0_.user_id =?
        AND orgmessage0_.peer_id =?
    ORDER BY
        orgmessage0_.message_id DESC
) WHERE rownum <= 10;
```

Is there any solution to add the query hint to the right place?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try two solutions here:

1. Use Pageable instead of setMaxResult() to keep going with HQL
2. Use createNativeQuery() with limit option to retrieve correct result